# Angularjs model not update view when modified by child controller

Tags: angularjs

I have to update a parameter of the parent controller from a nested controller.
I'm able to read the parameter, but when I change it it does not update into the view (webpage)... help plz :)

This is my js:

```
    app.controller('signalCtrl', [ '$scope', 'DB', function($scope, service) {
        this.address = null;
    }]);

    app.controller('reportMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        this.updateParent = function() {
            $scope.$parent.tab.address = 'something';
        }
    }]);
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="signalCtrl as signal">
    <input type="text" ng-model="signal.address">
    [...]
    <div ng-controller="reportMap as map">
    [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: To share variables between controllers without the $scope object, either use a shared service/directory, $rootScope events or $rootScope variables

Answer (score 0):

The `address` property in parent controller is not bound to `$scope`, but to `this` object, so you even can't reach that property that way. I suggest you to move your updating function to parent controller:

```
app.controller('signalCtrl', [ '$scope', 'DB', function($scope, service) {
    var self = this;
    self.address = null;
    self.update = function(newValue) {
        self.address = newValue;
    }
}]);

app.controller('reportMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.someValue = 'something';
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="signalCtrl as signal">
    <input type="text" ng-model="signal.address">
    [...]
    <div ng-controller="reportMap as map">
        <button type="button" ng-click="signal.update(map.someValue)">Click!</button>
    [...]
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't call updating function in the presented code, so I added a button to show how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how should I call the function from the child?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve. What's wrong with my answer? I don't see a reason why you would want to have this function in child.

Comment: I want to modify address progmatically from reportMap controller, but if I try it the {{signal.address}} does not update

Comment: Did you try my solution? I can't think of a reason to call it from child. However, if by some reasons you want to do this, there is Sandeep's answer which should work for you.

Comment: Yes, i tried. But it doesn't work, same problem as before

Answer (score 0):

use **signal** instead of **tab**

```
app.controller('reportMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.updateParent = function() {
        $scope.$parent.signal.address = 'something';
    }
}]);
```

see this link : https://plnkr.co/edit/RhQLfBy2heecJDuCcq9s?p=preview

Comment: this is a version mismatch, in my code there is already signal

Comment: I am not understand your fiddle. an alternate way u use $emit in child controller and $on in parent controller....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, probably the error is into te HTML:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('segnalazioni', ['filters', 'smart-table', 'smart-table-server']);

app.controller('nuovaSegnalazioneCtrl', [ '$scope', 'DB', function($scope, service) {
    var self = this;
    this.activatedTab = "tab_animale";
    this.chipNumber = null;
    this.indirizzo = 'ind';


    this.setIndirizzo = function() {
        self.indirizzo = "VIA ROMA";
        console.log("AGGIORNAMENTO INDIRIZZO");

    }
```

I call setIndirizzo from the child (i don't pass a value I know, but it is not the problem): into the console i read "AGGIORNAMENTO INDIRIZZO", but the value into the VIEW does not change...

this is a link to the complete html file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzlm997ub8fot7r/html.txt?dl=0